# Android Studio upgrade patch is failing when upgrading to 0.9

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to upgrade my android studio from 0.8.9 to 0.9.9 and I have run into the error below:

[image: Patch failure message]

How do I resolve this?
And do I have to download the patch again? Is the patch saved somewhere so that I can apply it from my harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

> Some of the conflicts bewlow do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied.

My `NOTICE.txt` looks like:

```
This software includes code from IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
Copyright (C) JetBrains s.r.o.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
```

My `build.txt` is `AI-{build number}` so you probably can update it manually to your currently installed build.

The other files will be treated as stated in `Solution`, so backup if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for fixing `build.txt` conflict:

1) Open Android Studio -> Help -> About.

2) Make a screenshot, because the dialog closes it self every time it looses focus.

3) Open your `build.txt` file. You should find in the root of your Android Studio folder.

4) Update `build.txt` to match build number in About (without leading hash of course).

[image]

5) Restart Android Studio update from Help -> Check for update...